# update-alternative too many symbolic links

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install Juniper Network connect 32 bit on my 64 bit Ubuntu 14.10. following the documentation [here](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25230)

Network connect needs the java 32 bit to be installed along with the 64 java. 
those are some commands i used while installing java 64:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/java" 1

 sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/javaws" 1

 sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/javaws
```

Next I installed java 32 under this directory Usr/local/Java32/jre.8.0_31.
Im trying as written in the tutorial to make Network Connect link to Java32 instead of java64 while jave 64 is the default. so I'm using this command line:

```
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java32/jre1.8.0_31/bin/java 10.
```

But it is not working! i tried it different times with different changes and ofcourse i got this message:
     too many levels of symbolic links

how do i undo all the update-alternatives i made? and what is the right way to link to java 32?

Answer (score -1):

Use this command to start network connect which i am reproducing from the same juniper's page (there is a bug in the command. use -jar & not -cp as given by them). please note the NC.jar sits in your $HOME/.juniper_networks/

And in the command, for  give java 6 bin path (in your case, /usr/java32/hre1.8.0_31/bin/java)

```
    <java_path> -jar NC.jar -h <ivehostname> -u <username> -p <password> [-r <realm>] 
-f <ivecertificate_in_der_format> [-l <gui_log_level> [-L <ncsvc_log_level>] [-y <proxy> -
z <proxy_port> [-s <proxy_username> -a <proxy_password> [-d <proxy_domain>]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! but i have first to solve the loop of the "too many levels of symbolic links", Do you know how it is done?
thank you.

Comment: i see a bug here, sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java32/jre1.8.0_31/bin/java 10.  You might have to remove the extra arg "10." at the end...

Comment: this extra argument is the priority and as i read it is important.

Comment: if you use my answer, you don't need to use update-alternatives at all.. since only juniper's NC uses java32, only for NC.jar you can give full path